# The "InboxMessages Methods" documentation is down

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, mobilepush-ios

The "InboxMessages Methods" documentation. is down, is there any other place that has official documentation?

[image]

[image]

https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/inbox/inbox.html

https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/appledoc/Classes/MarketingCloudSDK.html#task_InboxMessages%20Methods

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the newest iOS documentation is here:

https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/appledocs/MarketingCloudSdk/8.0/index.html

And more specifically:

https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/appledocs/MarketingCloudSdk/8.0/Classes/MarketingCloudSDKInboxMessagesDataSource.html